# Retaining LogGroup and reusing it when redeploy the Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a CF stack where I create a Lambda and a LogGroup to this lambda. For now, no deletion policy is in place for the LogGroup.

I would like to implement a solution where we keep LogGroup retained even though the stack is deleted in AWS so that we don't lose the logs. I was able to do this by adding

```
UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
DeletionPolicy: Retain
```

to the LogGroup resource.

**My question is:** We are having rare cases where we need to delete the stack and recreate it, in these cases, when I delete the CF stack, LogGroup will stay there. When I try to recreate the stack, I am getting "***LogGroup already created***" warning and can't create stack.
How can I achieve this with a single CF template? I need some kind of "Create if not exists, otherwise use existing one" functionality for the LogGroup.

**NOTE:** This is achieveable by creating the log group with a separate CF template and import log group name to the service's CF, however I don't want to keep the creation & usage of LogGroup separate.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This probably won't be what you're looking for, but if you don't create the LogGroup explicitly as a resource, it won't get deleted if you tear down your stack. Then if you recreate the stack with the same name, the Lambda name will (presumably) be the same, and as a result the same/existing log group will be used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @404, but indeed this is not what I am looking for. The approach you mentioned is achievable if I take the LogGroup resource out of the stack.

Comment: Unless someone else has a better idea, I'll say this is not achievable with basic cloudformation because any resources declared in there are created only, there is no concept of "create or use existing". However this could be achieved via a lambda-backed custom resource. The lambda will check if the log group exists; if not it will create it, and in either case it will return the id or arn or whatever value you may need from it. I don't know how much you know about custom resources but I've used them quite extensively and this can be easily accomplished like that.

Comment: "LogGroup already created" can happen even without deleting the whole stack. In my case I documented the workaround [here](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/discussions/10805#discussioncomment-2601085)